# Why does my function not take my updated dataframe?

Tags: r, shiny

I have some function that takes a few dataframes that are dynamic.

```
out <-eventReactive(input$run_button, {
    HSDMIX_solve(newdataframe(), iondat(), cindat(), timeconverter(), nt_report)})
```

The problem I have with this function is with the argument iondat(). iondat() is a dynamic dataframe created through the following. The function does not take the updated dataframe.

```
iondat<-reactiveVal()
  
  observe({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "xlsx", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    ions<-read_xlsx(file$datapath, sheet=2)
    
    iondat(ions)
  })
```

Then updated as such

```
 observeEvent(input$add, {
    iondat(tibble::add_row(iondat(), name=input$name, mw=input$mw, KxA=input$KxA, valence=input$valence, kL=input$kL, Ds=input$Ds))  
  })
  
  output$IonsTable<-renderTable({iondat()})
```

but when I run it through the function

```
 out <-eventReactive(input$run_button, {
    HSDMIX_solve(newdataframe(), iondat(), cindat(), timeconverter(), nt_report)})
```

It takes the initial version of iondat() that hasn't been updated by the user. What is strange to me is that the dataframe *does* update in real time. I can visually see the rows being added. But when it's called in the function it takes the version of iondat() that was originally uploaded. Can someone explain the misunderstanding that I am having?

Comment: I would assume that the `observeEvent` updating `iondat` would trigger _first_, since `observe*` tends to be more-greedy/faster than `reactive*` blocks, but it's possible that you have an order of reactivity. Regardless, I suggest replacing your `observeEvent` with `iondat2 <- eventReactive(iondat(), { add_row(iondat(), ...); })` and then `HSDMIX_solve(newdataframe(), iondat2(), ...)`. That way at a minimum you have much more control over using already-updated data.

Comment: (Curious ... `ext == "xlsx"` and `"upload a csv"`? I guess I would have assumed `"upload xlsx"`, or something more flexible such as `ext %in% c("csv", "xlsx")` and conditional use of `readxl::read_xlsx` or `readr::read_csv` or such. Mostly a curiosity/note :-)